# How to iterate over a class that contains list of two classes? - RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

This is my data :

```
{
  "-JxsJFiGBqQz1KQmmR0i" : {
    "bizcardData" : {
      "company" : "Tesla",
      "designation" : "Developer",
      "email" : "phani@tesla.com",
      "name" : "Phani",
      "phone" : "5135921241"
    },
    "transData" : {
      "date" : "15-08-29",
      "location" : "39.1395996,-84.5295417",
      "tag" : "sender",
      "time" : "03:17:00"
    }
  },
  "-JxsJKnJIVTFQWE1aSOr" : {
    "bizcardData" : {
      "company" : "Spotify",
      "designation" : "Designer",
      "email" : "komarapa@spotify.com",
      "name" : "Phani Komaravolu",
      "phone" : "5135921241"
    },
    "transData" : {
      "date" : "15-08-29",
      "location" : "39.1395996,-84.5295417",
      "tag" : "sender",
      "time" : "03:17:21"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Transactions class :

```
public class Transactions
    {
            public BizcardData bizcardData { get; set; }
            public TransData transData { get; set; }
    }

public class BizcardData
{
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string designation { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class TransData
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```

That I deserialized using RestSharp :

```
var resultList = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Transactions>>(content);

            Console.WriteLine ("Deserialized resultList"+resultList);

            foreach(var item in resultList)
            {
                var key = item.Key;
                var value = item.Value;

            /*  foreach(Transactions go in item.Value)
                {
                    var bizcardData = go.bizcardData;
                    var transData = go.transData;

                }*/
            }
```

This code gives me the Key as the unique values and the value as Transaction.

If I try to iterate over the Transaction class, I am getting an error saying that, must implement IEnumerable. How can I iterated over the transaction class and get the values.

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: You can't, since you chose to deserialize the data into meaningful objects (instead of a `Dictionary`), you must use the property names to retrieve the values manually. Long answer: you can (but shouldn't) use reflection to retrieve the list of properties of your object and iterate over that - in your case, though, it would definitely be more work than quickly writing out those few properties by hand. Question: What is your goal with those loops? Maybe there is an entirely different&simpler solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the keys you can just iterate over the dictionary's values (Transactions).

```
var resultList = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Transactions>>(content);

Console.WriteLine ("Deserialized resultList"+resultList);

foreach(var transaction in resultList.Values)
{
     var bizcardData = transaction.bizcardData;
     var transData = transaction.transData;
}
```

If you do care about the keys, just get rid of your second loop.

```
var resultList = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Transactions>>(content);

Console.WriteLine ("Deserialized resultList"+resultList);

foreach(var pair in resultList)
{
     var key = pair.Key;
     var transaction = pair.Value;
     var bizcardData = transaction.bizcardData;
     var transData = transaction.transData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not *a list of two classes*. What you've got is an `Object` (*Value*) of type `Transactions` which contains two properties:

```
item.Value.bizcardData
item.Value.transData
```